# Get multiple input type hidden value row button click for column in table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is sample column for single row where i have tried to get hidden value by button action event

```
<td colspan="2">
    <!-- the hidden value i want to retrieve "stockitemid" and "outletid"  -->
    <!-- value i have bind from controller through model like @item.ID= stockitemid and @item.OUTLET_ID=outletid -->
    <input type="hidden" class="itemid" name="stockitemid" value="@item.ID"/>  
    <input type="hidden" class="oid" name="outletid" value="@item.OUTLET_ID"/>
    <div class="btn-toolbar row-action">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <!-- button action given below what i have tried to display value in modal form  controller. but every-time i click same value found from this event -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnitemaddtotray" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addtotrayModal" title="Add Item"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Hhere is my retrieval jquery code every time i get same "stockitemid" and "outletid"

```
<script>
    $('#btnitemaddtotray').click(function() {
       // this is what i have tried to get row index with column index value
       $('td').click(function () {
           var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
           var row =    $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
            alert('Row: ' + row + ', Column: ' + col);
        });  
        // here is itemid and outlet id i got every-time same value. 
        var itemid = $('input[name=stockitemid]').val();
        var outletid =$('input[name=outletid]').val();
    });
</script>
```

I want to get hidden value from table where i have multiple row.

Comment: You cannot have a `.click()` handler within a `.click()` handler. And suplicare `id` attributes are invalid html. Use class names instead. - `$('.btn').click(function() { var cell= $(this).closest('td'); var itemid  = cell.find('.itemid').val(); ... });`

Comment: thank you..it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

ID should always be unique to each element, so I am using a class instead. Use of `parents()` will give you the the container to `find()` the hidden inputs in to retrieve the values.

```js
$('.btnitemaddtotray').on('click',function() {
  
  var btn = $(this),
      row = btn.parents('td').first();
      itemId = row.find('.itemid').val(),
      oid = row.find('.oid').val();
      
      console.log(itemId,oid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <input type="hidden" class="itemid" name="stockitemid" value="@item.ID"/>  
    <input type="hidden" class="oid" name="outletid" value="@item.OUTLET_ID"/>
    <div class="btn-toolbar row-action">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btnitemaddtotray" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addtotrayModal" title="Add Item">Add Item</button>
    </div></div>
    </td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <input type="hidden" class="itemid" name="stockitemid" value="@item.ID2"/>  
    <input type="hidden" class="oid" name="outletid" value="@item.OUTLET_ID2"/>
    <div class="btn-toolbar row-action">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btnitemaddtotray" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addtotrayModal" title="Add Item">Add Item</button>
    </div></div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```